# Merging GDML files

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

The GDML manual documents how to setup multiple GDML files as follows.

[image: Multiple GDML files]

Now lxml has a facility to parse multiple files as follows

```
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=True)
root= etree.parse(filename, parser=parser)
```

I assume that at least under the covers it must combine the multiple files before parsing.

My question is there some way I can just save the combined files, as I would like to
have the facility to combine and save a LARGE ( > 100 ) number of xml files where they are specified as includes in a gdml file and discard the !ENTITY definitions.

note: I don't want to parse the files as for the large number this takes a long time.

I guess one option would be to code something like

```
 gdml = etree.tostring('gdml')
 etree.ElementTree(gdml).write('filename')
```

But have a concern that I might hit a max string size, which I understand would be limited to the maximum addressable.

```
   import sys
   sys.maxsize
```

Wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: A better way than having lxml resolve the entities on parse? Not in my opinion. You could always analyze the entity declarations to get the system identifiers and then process the rest of the GDML (XML) file as text and match the entity references and then replace them with the contents of the matching file, but you'd then have to manually cleanup the doctype to remove the entity declarations. (If you need them removed. Technically you could leave them.)  I'm also not sure how much processing time that would save.

Comment: Should have explained the situation better ROOT does not support multiple GDML files where as Geant4 does. Want to create a utility to process a multi file gdml set up and output just a single file that has no DOCTYPE, NO ENTITIES and no &includefile; that ROOT could handle. Needs to be able to handle a large number of includes. Might be better with unix/linux scripts but if could be done with python would be good.

Comment: Okayy having reread your comment. I think you are probably right, processing the identifiers and the includes would mean I could build up the final file by just append stuff as I go.